# Need Overview of Modern Java for Desktop Applications

Tags: java, desktop

I've been asked to write a cross-platform desktop app in Java.  Targeted platforms are Windows/OSX/Linux.

I learned Java 1.1 1997, and did a few small utilities and applets using the the AWT library.  I've done nothing with it since.

What modern technologies and libraries should I use for this project?  I'm just looking for a list so I can follow up with Google.  There is a lot of java stuff out there, and it  is difficult for an outsider to make sense of it all.

Also, do you have any broad tips on distribution, installation and auto-updating?

To give you an idea of my background, I've been writing complex desktop apps since 1988 in C, C++, Visual Basic, Delphi and C#.  Any tips you give me would really help me get a running start on this project.

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT:**  I will be doing a lot of custom controls, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) and [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit), because the first decision you will need to make will be to pick one of them, and it probably won't be feasible to switch later.

There are a lot of other general-purpose libraries that may be useful, e.g. [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), but those can be mixed and matched so that decision is not so critical.

Comment: +1, Swing/SWT is _the_ decision to make - I'd go for SWT myself. (Unless you need some other UI framework...).

Comment: I will be doing a lot of custom controls, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'd go for swing, there is ( in my opinion ) much more information/resources in the internet than SWT.

Comment: Shouldn't JavaFX also be an option?  From what I've heard of it, it's what I'd be using now.

Answer (score 4):

Basic Decision: Swing vs. SWT **vs. [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/)** (I'd go with this, possibly combined with Swing).

As for the "soft" other aspects (in addition to what was already mentioned):

- [JUnit](http://junit.org/) (Unit testing/TDD)
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (Continuous Integration)
- [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) (Mock Objects)

Answer (score 2):

Java has changed in several of important (design affecting) ways, you should make sure that you are aware of the new language features that have been introduced since 1997, such as generics.

Most changes/additions to the Java language should feel familiar since C# has many of the same features.

If you find yourself longing for C# lambda, check out [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)

Other than that most important things have been mentioned, so Ill give my personal opinion on them:

1. I would say use **[Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/)** over
   **SWT**
2. I would suggest that you look at
   both **[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)** and
       **[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org)** to see which environment feels more comfortable
       to develop in. But I think you may
       find more similarities between
       Visual Studio C# and **Netbeans**, than
       between VSC# and Eclipse
3. If you
       need advanced GUI components check
       out SwingX first.

Additionally, other than Stack Overflow, a great resource is [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/CatalogJava.htm), [Java2s - Swing](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/CatalogSwing-Components.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt) is a library you could use. And Eclipse for IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Swing is already a good technology to work with. But it is a little problematic to understand the basic concepts at the beginning.

You can read the [Swing Architecture](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) which will give you a very good understanding of what going on behind the scenes.

The [swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is a must read.

And finally, once you have a good understanding of the framework, you'll be able to get around this book:

[image]
<sub>(source: [filthyrichclients.org](http://filthyrichclients.org/images/book.png))</sub>

From the description page:

> *Filthy rich clients are applications that are so graphically rich that they ooze cool. They suck the user in from the outset and hang onto them with a death grip of excitement. They make the user tell their friends about the applications.*
>
> *In short, they make the user actually enjoy their application experience. When was the last time you enjoyed using a software application?*

The problem with most Swing apps, is they stay in the bare minimum and don't add eye candy to their interfaces, making it boring to use.

These book has a number of topics you can learn to improve the look of your swing app.

There is a [NetBeans plugin of the demos](http://www.curious-creature.com/2007/09/29/filthy-rich-clients-demos-as-netbeans-plugin/)

For instance [this article](https://www.javalobby.org//java/forums/t102036.html) describes how to apply some of these concepts and create a busy pane like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [javalobby.org](https://www.javalobby.org//images/postings/geertjan/pics/glasspane-painting-jl2.png))</sub>

Comment: I am renewing my safari.oreilly.com subscription just so I check out this book.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Swing, SWT and the NetBeans platform there are a few other words you should google :)

1. JIDE (components)
2. SwingX (components)
3. Substance (Look n Feel)
4. FEST (automated testing framework for swing)
5. JXLayer (decorating components)

Answer (score 0):

> Also, do you have any broad tips on
>   distribution, installation and
>   auto-updating?

[Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) is a good solution for this.

Comment: I have to say I've found Web Start to be a miserable thing to work with. Before we stopped using JWS, the most frequent category of user complaint we had involved problems with it. We provide a Mac bundle, a Windows installer, and a Linux tarball now, and have virtually zero installation complaints these days.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend looking at [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/). It is a Java Swing based library that brings the plugin models and convention over configuration model from Grails to the Swing world. It does mean you would be coding in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) and not Java but that should not be a problem.

For a new application this would be a good choice. Groovy and Griffon run on the Java Virtual Machine and can be deployed cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Rich Client project](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html) is a complete Swing-based framework for creating Spring-based desktop applications, similar to Eclipse and NetBeans. i use it because it dramatically reduces the amount of boiler-plate code needed.